# Optimizing distance calculation between rows and matrices with numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, vector

I have an image processing problem where I am trying to create something known as a `histogram of activated patches`.

I have a codebook (a numpy array, 200X36) and an image (another numpy array, 128X128). For each pixel, I have to see which codebook vector is `nearest`.

The distance between a codebook vector and a pixel is defined as the Euclidean distance between the vector and a 6X6 patch left cornered at the pixel, which is reshaped to form a 1X36 vector.

For each pixel, I am extracting the patch and computing the nearest codebook vector using the code `d,i=spatial.KDTree(cData).query(patch.reshape((1,6*6)))`. But this is O(N) for number of pixels. Is there any way to improve the running time? A reasonable approximation is fine.

Comment: If you have to find the nearest vector *for each pixel*, wouldn't *any* algorithm be O(N), given that you at least need to read through the list of pixels? Or am I understanding incorrectly?

Comment: @Praveen, I had the same thought. I tried to work out a scheme for generating the matrix containing all patch vectors by multiplying the image pixel vector with a sparse boolean matrix and passing that to the query function, but I can't convince myself that it'd be any faster than iterating over the set of patches.